# Can a native library be included in an Android Studio project as a dependency?

Tags: android, android-studio, dependencies, shared-libraries, android-gradle-plugin

I have a working Android application that uses a native library (.so), which sits in the `jniLibs/armeabi-v7a` directory. The project is version controlled with git, and the only solution I have found to version control with the library is to commit the entire .so library to the git repository, which is a discouraged practice with git.

Is there a way to have gradle retrieve the native library similarly to the way it retrieves Maven dependencies? Or is it possible to package an Android library project that contains the native library so it can be retrieved as a Maven dependency?

Comment: 1. Yes of course, it's possible. A lot of libraries retrived as Maven dependencies contain native libraries. For example https://github.com/koral--/android-gif-drawable. 2. Don't forget that except `armeabi-v7a` there are several different architectures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Or is it possible to package an Android library project that contains the native library so it can be retrieved as a Maven dependency?

Sure. An AAR can contain native binaries. [SQLCipher for Android](https://www.zetetic.net/sqlcipher/open-source/) is one. My [AndDown](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-anddown) is another. In the case of AndDown, the library project contains the NDK sources.

If you do not have the NDK sources, you would have `jniLibs/` in the library project. The contents of `jniLibs/` would be packaged with the AAR, ready for you to upload to your favorite Maven-style repository.